# TCP Socket not getting closed disposed properly

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a static method

```
public class TelnetClient
{
    public static string SendAndReceiveData2(string data, string HostIPAddress, int Port)
    {
        using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            socket.Connect(HostIPAddress, Port);
            byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
            socket.SendTimeout = 3000;
            int bytesSent = socket.Send(bytesToSend);
            if (bytesSent != bytesToSend.Length)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid send byte number");
            }


            byte[] bytesReceiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRec = socket.Receive(bytesReceiveBuffer); //No need to loop for testing
            string returnedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceiveBuffer, 0, bytesRec);

            socket.Close(); // Just out of desperation
            socket.Dispose();
            return returnedData;
        }
    }
 }
```

and this is how I am calling it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TelnetClient.SendAndReceiveData2("some data different each time", "127.0.0.1", 1234);
}
```

I am calling this method in a loop. This methods sends some commands to a third party application which returns a response immediately. The issue is that this code works for the first iteration but on the second iteration, it fails at `socket.Receive` with error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection
>   failed because the connected host has failed to respond.

Here is the tricky part, If instead of looping multiple times, I close the `exe` and start again through command prompt, I don't get the error and also the third party app receives multiple requests as well.

This led me to believe that **somehow the socket is not getting disposed properly in the loop. But if I close the process and start again, it has no problem.**

I have checked that the `socket.LocalEndPoint` points to different port each time. Also `socket.Available` is set to `0` on second iteration.

I am not really sure what is going on, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Post the code that calls this method. It's basically fine, the error is elsewhere. You can delete that superstitious triple closing code, though.

Comment: @usr, just posted it.

Comment: @usr, basically on each iteration in the loop, I send a different string data, (different set of commands).

Comment: The code is fine. What code is the server running?

Comment: @usr, that is a third party app which provides a command interface through TCP connection.

Comment: OK, that app apparently is not sending you bytes withing 3sec. Could that be the case?

Comment: But in that case, if I close my application and restart it again, sending the command again, I get the response right away, *(I have also tried increasing the timeout to a larger number, 2 minutes)*

Comment: You've got a point there. If you ever find the answer ping me. I have no idea on how to debug this further which rarely happens.

Comment: socket.Close(); socket.Dispose(); are redundant in this using block.

Comment: Could it be that the server responds to the first "data" but not to the second "data"? Hard-code the data to be the first item always. Does the loop now make progress?

Comment: @usr, just tried that same exception, hard coded same command is even failing with the same exception.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea, this shows more of a desperation at my end rather than knowledge :), I know `using` block should translate to `try-finally` , which could call the `Dispose` but just trying everything :)

Comment: Why are you using raw sockets? Just use `TcpClient`. The API is still not all that high-level, but it's much easier to use anyway. Whether the socket is released or not is irrelevant - it would only become an issue when you run out of ports. Since you're only trying 10 sends, this is not the case (unless you've got another application opening hundreds of TCP connections per second). Also, the socket is rarely fully released in less than about two minutes. The way it looks, it might be the other side that handles TCP incorrectly - try using Wireshark to monitor the raw network communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the Socket and Socket disposal. The error message was bit misleading. The issue was at the server end.

More details....

Invalid data was being sent on the second iteration, when I tried sending exactly same data as the first iteration, it failed as well, because for each requests the server required a unique `Guid` id. That `Guid` was being generated outside the loop and hence it was used for all the items in the iteration. Restarting the process was working, because then I would get a new `Guid` for the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are doing a Socket.Connect, but never doing a Socket.Disconnect.

From the MSDN website [Socket.Disconnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnect(v=vs.110).aspx) will allow reuse of the socket and close the connection.